# YouCompleteMe :YcmDiag E788 can not edit another buffer now?

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

Why can not YCM edit its own buffer?

```
Diagnostics refreshed
Error detected while processing function <SNR>187_ShowDiagnostics:
line    1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ubuntu/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 832, in ShowDiagnostics
    vimsupport.OpenLocationList( focus = True )
  File "/home/ubuntu/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm/vimsupport.py", line 385, in OpenLocationList
    vim.command( 'lopen' )
vim.error: Vim(loadview):E788: Not allowed to edit another buffer now
```

My `.ycm_extra_conf.py`:

```
# This file is NOT licensed under the GPLv3, which is the license for the rest
# of YouCompleteMe.
#
# Here's the license text for this file:
#
# This is free and unencumbered software released into the public domain.
#
# Anyone is free to copy, modify, publish, use, compile, sell, or
# distribute this software, either in source code form or as a compiled
# binary, for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, and by any
# means.
#
# In jurisdictions that recognize copyright laws, the author or authors
# of this software dedicate any and all copyright interest in the
# software to the public domain. We make this dedication for the benefit
# of the public at large and to the detriment of our heirs and
# successors. We intend this dedication to be an overt act of
# relinquishment in perpetuity of all present and future rights to this
# software under copyright law.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND,
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF
# MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.
# IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR
# OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE,
# ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR
# OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
#
# For more information, please refer to <http://unlicense.org/>

import os
import ycm_core

# These are the compilation flags that will be used in case there's no
# compilation database set (by default, one is not set).
# CHANGE THIS LIST OF FLAGS. YES, THIS IS THE DROID YOU HAVE BEEN LOOKING FOR.
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-Werror',
'-Wno-long-long',
'-Wno-variadic-macros',
'-DNDEBUG',

# THIS IS IMPORTANT! Without a "-std=<something>" flag, clang won't know which
# language to use when compiling headers. So it will guess. Badly. So C++
# headers will be compiled as C headers. You don't want that so ALWAYS specify
# a "-std=<something>".
# For a C project, you would set this to something like 'c99' instead of
# 'c++11'.
'-std=c99',

# ...and the same thing goes for the magic -x option which specifies the
# language that the files to be compiled are written in. This is mostly
# relevant for c++ headers.
# For a C project, you would set this to 'c' instead of 'c++'.
'-x', 'c',

'-I', '.',

'-I', './src/',

'-I', './include/',

'-I', './ClangCompleter',

'-isystem', '../llvm/include',

'-isystem', '../llvm/tools/clang/include',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/gtest',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/gtest/include',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock',

'-isystem', './tests/gmock/include',

'-isystem', '/usr/include',

'-isystem', '/usr/local/include',

'-isystem', './platform',
'-isystem', './platform/base',
'-isystem', './platform/base/RFCGeneral/',
'-isystem', './platform/base/RFCGeneral/event',

'-I', './platform',
'-I', './platform/base',
'-I', './platform/base/RFCGeneral/',
'-I', './platform/base/RFCGeneral/event',
]

# Set this to the absolute path to the folder (NOT the file!) containing the
# compile_commands.json file to use that instead of 'flags'. See here for
# more details: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html
#
# Most projects will NOT need to set this to anything; you can just change the
# 'flags' list of compilation flags. Notice that YCM itself uses that approach.
compilation_database_folder = ''

if os.path.exists( compilation_database_folder ):
  database = ycm_core.CompilationDatabase( compilation_database_folder )
else:
  database = None

SOURCE_EXTENSIONS = [ '.cpp', '.cxx', '.cc', '.c', '.m', '.mm' ]

def DirectoryOfThisScript():
  return os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


def MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, working_directory ):
  if not working_directory:
    return list( flags )
  new_flags = []
  make_next_absolute = False
  path_flags = [ '-isystem', '-I', '-iquote', '--sysroot=' ]
  for flag in flags:
    new_flag = flag

    if make_next_absolute:
      make_next_absolute = False
      if not flag.startswith( '/' ):
        new_flag = os.path.join( working_directory, flag )

    for path_flag in path_flags:
      if flag == path_flag:
        make_next_absolute = True
        break

      if flag.startswith( path_flag ):
        path = flag[ len( path_flag ): ]
        new_flag = path_flag + os.path.join( working_directory, path )
        break

    if new_flag:
      new_flags.append( new_flag )
  return new_flags


def IsHeaderFile( filename ):
  extension = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 1 ]
  return extension in [ '.h', '.hxx', '.hpp', '.hh' ]


def GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename ):
    # The compilation_commands.json file generated by CMake does not have entries
    # for header files. So we do our best by asking the db for flags for a
    # corresponding source file, if any. If one exists, the flags for that file
    # should be good enough.
    if IsHeaderFile( filename ):
        basename = os.path.splitext( filename )[ 0 ]
        for extension in SOURCE_EXTENSIONS:
            replacement_file = basename + extension
            if os.path.exists( replacement_file ):
                compilation_info = database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( replacement_file )
                if compilation_info.compiler_flags_:
                    return compilation_info
        return None
    return database.GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )


def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ):
  if database:
    # Bear in mind that compilation_info.compiler_flags_ does NOT return a
    # python list, but a "list-like" StringVec object
    compilation_info = GetCompilationInfoForFile( filename )
    if not compilation_info:
      return None

    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute(
      compilation_info.compiler_flags_,
      compilation_info.compiler_working_dir_ )

    # NOTE: This is just for YouCompleteMe; it's highly likely that your project
    # does NOT need to remove the stdlib flag. DO NOT USE THIS IN YOUR
    # ycm_extra_conf IF YOU'RE NOT 100% SURE YOU NEED IT.
    try:
      final_flags.remove( '-stdlib=libc++' )
    except ValueError:
      pass
  else:
    relative_to = DirectoryOfThisScript()
    final_flags = MakeRelativePathsInFlagsAbsolute( flags, relative_to )

  return {
    'flags': final_flags,
    'do_cache': True
  }
```

The output of `:YcmDebuggInfo"

```
Printing YouCompleteMe debug information...
-- Resolve completions: Up front
-- Client logfile: /tmp/ycm_iifk1o7e.log
-- Server Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
-- Server Python version: 3.8.10
-- Server has Clang support compiled in: False
-- Clang version: None
-- Extra configuration file found and loaded
-- Extra configuration path: /home/ubuntu/workspace/proj/.ycm_extra_conf.py
-- C-family completer debug information:
--   Clangd running
--   Clangd process ID: 14913
--   Clangd executable: ['/home/ubuntu/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/clangd/output/bin/clangd', '-log=verbose', '-pretty', '-header-insertion-decorators=0', '-resource-dir=/home/ubuntu/.vim/plugged/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/clang/lib/clang/13.0.0']
--   Clangd logfiles:
--     /tmp/clangd_stderr5hvc2xhc.log
--   Clangd Server State: Initialized
--   Clangd Project Directory: /home/ubuntu/workspace/roc_rsp_shell
--   Clangd Settings: {}
--   Clangd Compilation Command: False
-- Server running at: http://127.0.0.1:43927
-- Server process ID: 14873
-- Server logfiles:
--   /tmp/ycmd_43927_stdout_qts9v8rd.log
--   /tmp/ycmd_43927_stderr_saz7qf73.log
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl. I'm not sure it is a bug or something I did wrong.

Comment: I think I found a clue now. I in the code i include <event/service_event.h> but it is not found [pp_file_not_found]. And that seams to make the Ycm to crash!?

Comment: Whether it is a YCM bug or you doing something, this question is definitely not about programming. Dump your config and diagnostics into their issue tracker, that's why it exists.